# how to do a proof for subset in Isabelle

Tags: set, isabelle, proof

I'm trying to do some proofs  manually in Isabelle but I'm struggling with the following proof:
`lemma "(A ∩ B) ∪ C ⊆ A  ∪ C "`

I'm trying to transform it Propositional Logic then prove it.

So here's what I tried:

```
 lemma "(A ∩ B) ∪ C ⊆ A  ∪ C "
  apply (subst subset_iff)+
  apply(rule allI)
  apply (rule impI)
 (*here normally we should try to get rid of Union and Inter*)
  apply(subst Un_iff)+ 
  apply(subst  (asm)  Un_iff)+
  apply(subst Inter_iff) (*not working*)
```

I'm stuck at the last step, could someone please help me finish this proof and explain how should one find the right theorems till the end?

I use find_theorems, but it takes a lot of time + the only useful (and understandable) ressource I found so far is this link:
https://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/ar/isabelle/FormalCheatSheet.pdf
and some very few random lecture notes  containing almost the same content as the link above...

Other resources I found are 100+ pages and do not look like a place to start for a beginner...

Thanks in advance

Comment: wrong intersection theorem... You want Int_iff.

Comment: why on earth do you even want to do that apply style? Every Isabelle lecture teaches you to do `by blast` (one step). Anyway, http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2020/doc/tutorial.pdf, Section 5 documents this kind of proofs.

Comment: @MathiasFleury, what a coincidence, I happened to be reading a few documents that mentioned your name a few days ago  I'm aware that blast can do it, but the online course I'm following suggested that we do it manually. it's the `Int_iff` tip that I needed, thanks a lot!

Comment: There are a lot of different approaches to teaching Isabelle. Some think it is best to teach such very low-level reasoning first. I don't think I agree, but it's not unreasonable. In any case, I have been using Isabelle for a long time and I usually only use low-level tactics like `subst`, `rule`, etc. as a first step and then hit all the arising subgoals with automation like `auto`. That is more typical of the style we use these days. And of course structured Isar proofs. But I'm sure your course will get there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First writing such kind of proofs manually is not useful as it can be solved by blast. It is mostly reserved for advanced users. The only documentation I know is [the old tutorial](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2020/doc/tutorial.pdf), Section 5.

Anyway, you have the wrong intersection theorems: you want to use `Int_iff`. Here is the full proof:

```
lemma "(A ∩ B) ∪ C ⊆ A  ∪ C "
  apply (subst subset_iff)+
  apply(rule allI)
  apply (rule impI)
    (*here normally we should try to get rid of Union and Inter*)
  apply(subst Un_iff)+ 
  apply(subst  (asm)  Un_iff)
  apply(subst (asm) Int_iff)
  apply (elim disjE)
   apply (elim conjE)
   apply (rule disjI1)
   apply assumption
  apply (rule disjI2)
  apply assumption
  done
```

How did would I find such proof? I know by heart the low-level theorems on implication, conjunction, and disjunction (`allI, impI, conjI, conjE, disjE, disjI1`,...). There is a consistent naming convention (`I`: intro rule, `E`: elimination rule, `D`: destruction rule), so it is not so hard to remember.

For the rest, searching with find_theorems (or the query panel) is the way to go.

Here is the proof I would write (but the other one is nicer for teaching: conjE is way more important than IntE):

```
lemma "(A ∩ B) ∪ C ⊆ A  ∪ C "
  apply (rule subset_iff[THEN iffD2])
  apply(intro allI impI)
  apply (elim UnE)
   apply (elim IntE)
   apply (rule UnI1)
   apply assumption
  apply (rule UnI2)
  apply assumption
  done
```

Comment: I believe that it may also be worth mentioning, perhaps, the most natural solution using an `apply` style script: `lemma "(A ∩ B) ∪ C ⊆ A ∪ C" by (intro Un_mono inf_sup_ord basic_monos)`. Also, with regard to "writing such kind of proofs manually is not useful as it can be solved by blast", surely, sometimes, explicit invocation of specific rules can improve efficiency: the proofs found by blast/auto/etc can (sometimes) be unnecessarily convoluted.